# python3 throwing ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I am running into following error on python3 when running `botocore` module,any guidance on how to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wifi_build_audit_10_1", line 37, in <module>
    config=botocore.client.Config(read_timeout=300)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 91, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 838, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 81, in create_client
    cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 114, in _create_client_class
    base_classes=bases)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 61, in _handler
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 52, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 15, in <module>
    from boto3.s3.transfer import create_transfer_manager
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 127, in <module>
    from s3transfer.exceptions import RetriesExceededError as \
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.7.8/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures
```